# getting current fragment in Cardview

Tags: java, android

I have 3 fragments which are:

Fragment A
Fragment B and
Fragment C

they all have method `loadmore()`.

I tried to use `onScroll` listener to get to the bottom of the `Cardview` but it's not working so I tried doing it in the `getview()` method of the `Cardview`. 
My problem is now that, how can I call the `loadmore()` method from the current method?

Comment: Wait, since when cardview has adapter or even can scroll without attaching a scrollable child to it or its parent layout as scrollable. Please be more specific to help you

Comment: what kind of cardview you are working on? the supported Cardview from android.support package does have an Adapter? do you mean **RecyclerView**?